# AWK / Grep and Print All Matching Record

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, awk, aws-cli

I have this command which displays all the record from the search. But I would like to filter only the record that matches the search word.

For e.g.

```
for user in $(aws iam list-users |grep -i UserName|sed -e 's/.*: \"//' -e 's/\",//'); do 
    echo USER: $user; 
    echo TAGS:
    aws iam list-user-tags --user-name $user --output text | awk '{print $2,$3}'
    echo GROUPS:
    aws iam list-groups-for-user  --user-name $user --output text|awk {'print $5'};  done > users.txt
```

The above command displays the following results.

```
User: joe.blogs@abc.com
TAGS:
Team red
Status active
Environment: nonprod
GROUPS:
iam-nonprod
iam-prod

User: black.smith@abc.com
TAGS:
Team green
Status active
Environment: nonprod
GROUPS:
iam-nonprod
iam-prod

etc.
```

I would like get all the user where tag Team == red.

I tried with search string in line 4 like,

```
aws iam list-user-tags --user-name $user --output text | awk '/red/{print $2,$3}'

but it displays only one line

Team red

But I would like to display full record like

User: joe.blogs@abc.com
TAGS:
Team red
Status active
Environment: nonprod
GROUPS:
iam-nonprod
iam-prod
```

Could you please help how I can display all the record where tag Team == red.

Comment: You can use `aws iam list-users --output text --query "Users[].UserName"` to get a list of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with various awscli commands and the use of the `--query` option which allows you to perform conditional client-side filtering.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERS=$(aws iam list-users --query "Users[*].UserName" --output text)

for user in $USERS; do
    TAG=$(aws iam list-user-tags --user-name $user --query 'Tags[?(Key==`Team` && Value==`red`)]' --output text)

    if [ "$TAG" != "" ]; then
        echo "User:" $user

        echo "Tags:"
        aws iam list-user-tags --user-name $user --query 'Tags[*].[Key,Value]' --output text | tr "\t" "="

        echo "Groups:"
        aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name $user --query "Groups[*].GroupName" --output text | tr "\t" "\n"
    fi
done
```

Sample output:

```
User: jason
Tags:
Team=red
Role=development
Groups:
dev
User: mary
Tags:
Team=red
Role=test
Groups:
qa
ut
fv
```

Comment: Jarmod, Thank you very much. A new requirement. How can I include to show the policies attached to each group and then the each policy details. For e.g. the first cmd will show the policies attached to each group, list-group-policies --group-name, then 2nd cmd will show the policy details for each policy, get-group-policy --group-name --policy-name.

Answer (score 4):

For awk, you can use the paragraph mode. This will display all "records" that contain `Team red`.

```
awk -v RS= '/Team red/'
```

Comment: I was doing the same with `awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"} /Team red/{print}' file` but I like yours better.

Comment: I tried both of your command but it not give the expected result. 

`for user in $(aws iam list-users |grep -i UserName|sed -e 's/.*: \"//' -e 's/\",//'); do 
    echo USER: $user; 
    echo TAGS:
    aws iam list-user-tags --user-name $user --output text | awk -v RS= '/Team red/'
    echo GROUPS:
    aws iam list-groups-for-user  --user-name $user --output text|awk {'print $5'};  done > users.txt
`

I get all the results not just team red but also the result is missing the Tags

`User: joe.blogs@abc.com
TAGS:
GROUPS:
iam-nonprod
iam-prod`

Comment: @PaulHodges FYI `RS="\n\n"` requires GNU awk or a couple of other variants that support multi-char RS, otherwise it'll be treated as `RS="\n"` per POSIX, while `RS=""` will work in any awk.

Comment: Exactly. While it might not matter on my system, it's really not the best option in general.

Answer (score 0):

It's super easy with AWK. First put your data in a file and this command will do whole job:

```
awk '/Team red/{c=4} c-->-2' < file
```

```
$ cat myfile
User: joe.blogs@abc.com
TAGS:
Team red
Status active
Environment: nonprod
GROUPS:
iam-nonprod
iam-prod

User: black.smith@abc.com
TAGS:
Team green
Status active
Environment: nonprod
GROUPS:
iam-nonprod
iam-prod

etc.
$ awk '/Team red/{c=4} c-->-2' < file
User: joe.blogs@abc.com
TAGS:
Team red
Status active
Environment: nonprod
GROUPS:
iam-nonprod
iam-prod
[brhosh@scp-3-scripting(enm2) test]$
```

Comment: it is not working. I created 4 sample users with tags. Only the 4th user had tags 'Team red'. When I ran your cmd, it showed the first User email ID and then tag values of 4th user.